# API key is disabling in MailChimp when I try to subscribe in my php project

Tags: php, mailchimp, api-key

I have a php project where I used mailChimp. It is hosted in github and linked with heroku. but MailChimp continuously disabling the api key. how can I resolve this issue.
If I make my repository private will it resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

You should never be publishing your mailchimp api key anywhere. Otherwise bad people will find it, and use it, and you will lose your account and data.

If you set it private, that may keep them from finding that its on github.

You might also look into using [.gitignore](https://help.github.com/articles/ignoring-files/). You could include a file - mc_api_key.php or similar, with a single define statement or similar global variable.

Upload that to Heroku, keep it on your development machine. Use git ignores to never push it to github.